# how to filter Driver<[Repository]> objects in rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

```
struct SearchViewModel {
    lazy var rx_SearchResults: Driver<[Repository]> = self.fetchSearchResults()
    lazy var rx_FilteredSearchResults: Driver<[Repository]> = self.filteredSearchResults()
    fileprivate var searchQuery: Observable<String>
    fileprivate var scopeIndex:  Observable<Int>
init( searchTextObservable: Observable<String>, changeInScopeIndex: Observable<Int>)
    {
        self.searchQuery = searchTextObservable
        self.scopeIndex = changeInScopeIndex

    }
fileprivate func fetchRepositories() -> Driver<[Repository]> {
        return repositoryName
            .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // Make sure we are on MainScheduler
            .do(onNext: { response in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            })
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
            .flatMapLatest { text in // .background thread, network request
                return RxAlamofire
                    .requestJSON(.get, "https://api.github.com/users/\(text)/repos")
                    .debug()
                    .catchError { error in
                        return Observable.never()
                    }
            }
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
            .map { (response, json) -> [Repository] in // again back to .background, map objects
                if let repos = Mapper<Repository>().mapArray(JSONObject: json) {
                    return repos
                } else {
                    return []
                }
            }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // switch to MainScheduler, UI updates
            .do(onNext: { response in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            })
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []) // This also makes sure that we are on MainScheduler
    }

}
```

Now i am trying to filteredSearchResults like this

```
    **fileprivate  func filteredSearchResults() -> Driver<[FilesListSearchData]> {
        return scopeIndex
            .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // Make sure we are on MainScheduler
            .do(onNext: { response in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            })
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
            .map { index in // again back to .background, map objects
                return self.rx_SearchResults.asDriver()
            }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // switch to MainScheduler, UI updates
            .do(onNext: { response in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            })


}**
```

// Above method is wrong i am stuck how can i filter data now based on scope index.

As you people understood i am using MVVM I have two quires.

1. How can show progress on my view controller which is doing here by this line

   ```
           UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false/true
   ```
2. How can i filter Driver based on selected scope index.

Comment: 1. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift

Comment: Please, try to further clarify your question:
- What's your goal?
- What's exactly the error you're getting?

Comment: i have a array of models as Driver<[Model]> , i want to filter them based on some rule and return Driver<[Model]>.